# NPM docker command not override by alias podman

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, podman-compose

I'm migrating Docker to Podman and the alias not is working when invoked by npm.

I added  on my env alias:

```
alias docker='podman'
alias docker-compose='podman-compose'
```

To test the alias I ran `docker-compose up --build`  and works correctly using podman-compose, like expected.

I have on my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "docker-compose up --build",
    ...
```

When a I ran ***npm run start***, this is the output:

```
❯ npm run start

> project@1.0 start
> docker-compose up --build

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I did one more test, change the **docker-compose** to **podman-compose** on package.json file and works too.

#### Expected Behavior

Recognize the env alias. Like happen when I run the command direct on the terminal.

#### Steps To Reproduce

1. Set the podman alias over docker names.

```
alias docker='podman'
alias docker-compose='podman-compose'
```

2. Add a script on package.json to use the docker-compose.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "docker-compose up --build",
    ...
```

3. Run the npm script.

```
npm run start
```

#### Environment

- npm: 8.13.2
- Node.js: v14.19.3
- OS Name: macOS 12.4 (Monterey)
- System Model Name: Macbook Pro M1
- npm config:

```ini
❯ npm config ls
; node bin location = /Users/XPTO/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/bin/node
; node version = v14.19.3
; npm local prefix = /Users/XPTO
; npm version = 8.13.2
; cwd = /Users/XPTO
; HOME = /Users/XPTO
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

Answer (score 2):

I remove docker altogether, and add to /usr/local/bin/docker:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
podman "$@"
```

and /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
podman-compose "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe npm runs under different user where the aliases don't exist. Check it by adding id command to your start script.
Another guess: run it in a new terminal window to reload user environment.

Comment: Thanks @Kesha, but that not was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Check if you have your script-shell set to your terminal.
To check just use the command `npm config ls -l`

```
...
script-shell = null
searchexclude = ""
searchlimit = 20
searchopts = ""
searchstaleness = 900
shell = "/bin/zsh"
...
```

If your “script-shell“ value is null, set this value to your default terminal using this command `npm config set script-shell zsh` (the zsh is macOS Catalina default terminal) should do the trick here if you don't mind changing your shell for every project. if you'd rather be more specific, you can add `--location=project` to that command and a `.npmrc` file will be created in your project and the setting will only apply to that one project.

Here the source: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5153#issue-1302253170

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by:

1. Adding `alias docker='podman'` to `~/.zshenv`
2. Running `npm config set script-shell zsh`

See: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5153

Comment: npm config will update shell value with zsh fixing. It was my solution. Good to know works to you.